# Is reading a file in a view a bad practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Assuming a simple blog with a database in which the articles are maintained as:

```
 CREATE TABLE [Articles](
     [ArticleId] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [ContentURL] NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
     ....
 )
```

Would it be a good practice to include article's content in the view through reading the file located at `ContentURL` as: (To be particular, can be cache the file this way?)

```
@model Articles
...
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
       @Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Model.ContentURL))
   </div>
</div>
```

Or would it be better to do this in the controller and pass it as `ViewBag.RawContent`? (Does the `[OutputCache]` attribute help keep the file in memory?)

On the other hand, how about storing the raw content directly in the database using `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, is this the worst or the best practice?

Comment: It would be better if you read the file in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When answering this question, you have to think about a couple things:

- What happens if you can't read all the text?
- How often is the information going to change?
- How difficult is the proposed solution to manage?

We know that `File.ReadAllText()` can throw an exception if the file can't be found, or if it is locked, or if you don't have permissions to the file any longer.  We also know that if you have an exception in the `View`, the user gets the ugly error page.  Neither of those are desirable.

I think it's safe to say that `@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Model.ContentURL))` is a bad idea in the `View`.

> You need a way to recover if there does happen to be an exception thrown.

Your other solutions both provide the ability to handle the issues surrounding the first bullet.  They are also both pretty good solutions, so the answer for your project really depends on the answer to the next two bullets.

- If your file isn't going to change once you deploy the app, then populating the `ViewBag.RawContent` is perfectly good.
- You you need the ability for someone to edit that file without redeploying anything else, then you might want to use the database.

Comment: But we can always load the content as a file and modify it. What do you exactly mean by redeploying? Do you think that would result in any problem?

Comment: It's about management.  It's good practice to limit what files can be written to by the user account associated with the deployed app.  What works on a development machine may not work on a properly administered server.  So if files are read-only, you need to redeploy them to change the contents.  As to a problem, it just depends on how often you think this changes are going to be.  The threshold of when that becomes a problem is up to you.